# how to build a model for computer vision without using pre trained models

Tags: python, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I am a total rookie in computer vision. I am looking to build a model without using pre-trained models for coco dataset or any open-source image datasets. Any articles or references to build such models would be appreciated. I would like to build this model from scratch and make no suggestions on pre-existing trained models or Api are irrelevant to this question. and thanks in advance for any suggestions. the programming language of preference for this project is python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this tutorial on keras blogs:

https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Should be pretty straightforward and it is written in a step by step manner by the author of Keras. It has these three stages, but you only need the first one:

1. training a small network from scratch (as a baseline)
2. using the bottleneck features of a pre-trained network
3. fine-tuning the top layers of a pre-trained network